# 3DR Services on Android needs update but it is already up to date

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android

I'm using the first app set up from http://android.dronekit.io/first_app.html with Android Studio. When I load it onto my Samsung Galaxy S4 it gives me a pop up saying "Update 3DR Services! | Your version of 3DR Services must be updated to continue." I've tried uninstalling and re installing from Google Play. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that issue by specifying the version for the dronekit-android library dependency in the `build.gradle` file as such:

```
compile 'com.o3dr.android:dronekit-android:2.3.11'
```

The default dependency statement, `compile 'com.o3dr.android:dronekit-android:2.3.+'`, retrieves the latest version of the dronekit-android library. 
That version is usually in beta, and can only be used against the beta version of the `3DR Services` app.

You can find out which `dronekit-android` library version is the latest, and which version of `3DR Services` it requires from the [github release page](https://github.com/DroidPlanner/DroneKit-Android/releases/tag/dronekit-android-v2.3.11).